# mysql fetch_assoc_array?

Tags: php, mysql

Here is my problem,

Not using prepared statements I can do it just fine, for example,

```
    $qry = "SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE email = '$email'";
$result = mysql_query($qry);
$account = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
echo '<p>Welcome <strong>' . $account['username'] . '</strong>, Have a good day! And dont forgot your id ' . $account['id'] . '.</p>';
```

Considering an email does match a row on the mysql database, then I can with ease echo any other column where the email matches by simply doing $account['gender'], $account['age'] for example.

I am having alot of trouble doing it OO, here is my attempt;

```
$q = $dbc -> prepare ("SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE email = ?");
$q -> bind_param ('s', $email);
$q -> execute();
$q -> bind_result();
$info = $q -> fetch();
echo '<p>Welcome ' . $info['username'] . '.</p>';
```

Doing it with the first method I can display any information from any column where the email matches for that row, I switched to prepared statements for security, but I am thinking of switching back with the hassle it is causing!

Comment: If you're switching to OO, use PDO rather than Mysqli.

Comment: And what is your problem? You just say that you have a lot of trouble... but you are not telling us *what* is happening.

Comment: I cannot get it to echo any column information at all, I have a database where each row has around 300 columns, naming each of them in the query instead of using *, is too much of a hassle.

Comment: @Kalessin why would you use PDO?

Comment: @Basic: PDO has many advantages over Mysqli, including portability (it can be used with database engines other than MySQL), named placeholders (`$dbc->prepare("SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE email = ?")` versus `$dbc -> prepare ("SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE email = :email")`) and returning data as an object, as well as numeric and associative arrays.

Comment: Thank you alot, associative arrays are what I need, this will do the trick :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`bind_result` takes parameters.  You pass it the variables you want it to set, then you call `fetch`.

```
$q->bind_result($username);
$q->fetch();
echo $username;
```

For this to work, you need to change `SELECT *` to the fields you want, ie `SELECT username`.

If you still need to use `SELECT *`, you can do this:

```
$q->execute();
$r = $q->get_result();
while($row = $r->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Good old [MySQL](http://es.php.net/manual/en/book.mysql.php) extension does not support prepared statements so you must have switched to another extension you don't mention. If it happens to be [mysqli](http://es.php.net/mysqli), you're out of luck: it only supports associative arrays when you *don't* use prepared statements.

My advise is to try out [PDO](http://es.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php). The MySQL driver is stable and it has a great API you can reuse for other DBMS engines.

Comment: Ye mysqli is what I am using, if it doesn't support associative arrays then it is useless to me, PDO it is then, I just wasted my whole day trying to get that to work! Thanks.